# Uglifying AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an app I am demoing and want to demonstrate how dependency injection works. I have the following code:

```
wpApp.controller('ListCtrl', ['$scope', 'Posts', 'Pages', function($scope, Posts, Pages) {
  console.log('ListCtrl');
  $scope.page_title = 'Post Listing';
  Posts.query(function(res){
    $scope.posts = res;
  })
  Pages.query(function(resp) {
    $scope.pages = resp;
  })
}])
```

But when I run uglify on the code, I get the following:

```
wpApp.controller("ListCtrl",["$scope","Posts","Pages",function(t,o,s){console.log("ListCtrl"),t.page_title="Post Listing",o.query(function(o){t.posts=o}),s.query(function(o){t.pages=o})}]);
```

And the app breaks. Is there a step I am missing somewhere?

EDIT - **Problem is solved**. There was another dependency injection further down in the script that was missing and causing everything to go nuts.

Comment: Nothing shows up on the page other than the stuff outside my `<div ui-view></div>` tags

Comment: Any error in the js console?

Comment: In the browser console I meant

Comment: Nothing shows up in the console.

Comment: Scratch that, Firefox showed nothing, Chrome has an error... "angular.min.js?ver=1.5.5:40 Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr]"

Comment: The problem is not with the code you have provided, the minified version is functionally equivalent.

Comment: @thepio NO! How does angular know what to inject? Because it uses string matching on the first items in the array, so that it knows what to inject into the minified function. You're trying to remove the exact thing that angular uses to function properly on minified code.

Comment: Idiot question : have you included every files ? (including the new ones)

Comment: @Minipipo1 Yes.
I actually found the problem... It was my router function. Dep Injection was missing on that. On a hunch I added it and uglified and it worked just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try this as your uglify omit the `;`

```
wpApp.controller("ListCtrl",["$scope","Posts","Pages",function(t,o,s){console.log("ListCtrl");t.page_title="Post Listing";o.query(function(o){t.posts=o});s.query(function(o){t.pages=o})}]);
```

Answer (score -1):

Use `ng-annotate` with `gulp` or `grunt` as part of build process before bundling and minifying your angular code